# Get all strings surrounded by double quotes or single quotes in line with python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So far I have: (for context, I am parsing lines of code)

```
for line in file.readlines():
                        pattern = r'"((\\\\"|[^"])*")|\'((\\\\\'|[^\'])*\')'
                        matches = re.search(pattern, line)
```

however doing matches.group() only gives the first string in code that is caught, how can I get multiple strings in a single line.

Comment: Use `re.finditer`

Comment: I think you can simplify your regex to `([\'"])[^\1]*?\1` which uses backreferences to reuse the captured single or double quote.